# Doesn't print borders column in a new page Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

When column bigger than page this column stretch to a next page but other cells borders doesn't so I have full page of one column it looks horrible.
Do you know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: is any body knows the solution?